# 2 levels of lookup in sharepoint 2010,how to solve it?

Tags: sharepoint

I am doing  development in Sharepoint 2010. I have a small issue. There are 3 lists (say `list1`, `list2`, `list3`). `list1` has a column `col1`. Now, in list there is a lookup column called `col2` on `col1` of `list1`. This works very well for a single lookup.

Now, I need a column in list3 (say `col3`) which should be a lookup on `col2` of `list2`.
I am not getting this lookup (lookup on `col2` since `col2` itself is a lookup column).
Also, I don't want a direct lookup on `col1` in `list1`.

Is their any solution to this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should copy the looked up value into another column, say text column and lookup to it? You can copy using event receiver or I believe even using a simple WF in SPD